# Drupal 7 custom module/field for adding a task per hour

Tags: drupal, module, field

I am fairly new to Drupal and I am trying to create a simple content type where people can add their schedule for today.. for example from 2PM tot 4PM that person has to go to the gym.. So 2 dropdowns, 1 for every hour (2PM&4PM) and adding a textfield to that for "going to the gym" and the possibility to add more tasks.. (multiple values per day)

Any advice? Maybe a module or creating a custom field? Thx in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a content type "daily schedule" and attach multiple events to it (like 14:00 Gym, 16:00 Beer with friends), I would propose [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection). It would allow you to group time field (either simple numerical field or [Time field](https://drupal.org/project/timefield) with text field.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot! I have another simple question but can't seem to figure it out. For example I have from 14:00 to 16:00 a class, I would like for Drupal to remember the total hours (in this case 2) and store it in the database as a field.. Any idea's?

Comment: I would never go for another field in the database. I'd propose to calculate the period between beginning and end in a function when you need it. I took a look at Time Field module and it seems to provide a function which calculates time from midnight to given field time **timefield_time_to_integer($value)**. So take the end time, subtract the beginning time, handle contingency when beginning time is before and end time after midnight, and voila! It is a bit complex answer for comment... Sorry :)

Comment: No problem, I've solved the issue with computed field module, thx anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to go with contributed module intended to handle this kind of requirement. As per my understanding, you want to make functionlity for user to create their TODO list & there is a module which can do it easily for you - [myTinyTodo](https://drupal.org/project/mytinytodo).

Otherwise above answer is also good option to use [field_collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest content type + date module + calendar module.

1. install & enable Date Module. You will be able to add a date field to content type
2. Add new content type "Task"
3. Add 2 date fields "start" (2PM) and "end" (4PM) to your content type.

Users will be able to add as many tasks as they want. 
And finally, you can use Calendar module to preview task's list.